# Rails4 create a one to many relationship no need to add references in Migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

This is my Migration code:

```
    create_table :ploys do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.references :user

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Then i run this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then i check my database structure

But i not seen  **foreign key** and **refercences**

I use rails4 and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because rails by default don't create the foreign keys, you can use the gem: [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) to do this. and then add to your migration code:

```
 add_foreign_key(:ploys, :users)
```

The references only will create the foreign_key column (user_id) on the database. Take a look at: [Active Record and Referential Integrity](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity)